# Grails plugin class FilterPaneService doesn't show debug log

Tags: debugging, grails, plugins, log4j

I use `filterpane` plugin for grails and need to debug it's flow. In `Config.groovy` i put in log4j clause `debug  'org.grails.plugin.filterpane'`. It started logging to console from `FilterPaneUtils` but not from `FilterPaneService`, even thought both classes are from `org.grails.plugin.filterpane` package. I debugged code in `FilterPaneService` and it run through `log.debug` line but nothing appears on console.

What should I do to start logging from class `FilterPaneService`?

using Grails 2.1.1
and filterpane plugin 2.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this)
```

to the `FilterPaneService` class and it started logging. I'm not sure why the author of this plugin didn't put this declaration but without it it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
debug grails.app.services.org.grails.plugin.filterpane.FilterPaneService
```

Comment: Just to complement: Grails will append "grails.app.services" for all classes that lives in the service folder. This is the same deal for showing debug of your application services.

Comment: Thanks mate for adding the reasoning. That format of answer was the best I could do from my phone. ;) @SérgioMichels

Comment: Yeah dude, phone answering is a battle!

Comment: This is how it has been working from ages. Can we see what "other solution" was incorporated? :) @Gorky

Comment: Added ;] I think it's not the case of Config declaration but plugin class code.